# E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Int64'

Tags: delphi

I want to store the current date/time as a Unix timestamp in a database and am constructing an SQL query.

```
IntToStr(DateTimeToUnix(Now()))
```

> [dcc32 Error] fMainForm.pas(186): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Int64'

How do I get the current date/time as a Unix timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.DateUtils;

begin
  Writeln(IntToStr(DateTimeToUnix(Now())));
  Readln;
end.
```

Runs successfully and outputs the current Unix time. Therefore I conclude that code you have presented does not produce the error that you report. That error arises from some other code that is not part of the question.

Presumably you are taking that expression and trying to use it in an integer context. That would explain the error. If you need the value as an integer rather than a string then change

```
IntToStr(DateTimeToUnix(Now()))
```

to

```
DateTimeToUnix(Now())
```

This is a perfect example of why questions like this are better when presented with a MCVE.

Comment: D'oh!! Many years away from Delphi.

Comment: Note that `DateTimeToUnix()` returns an `Int64`, not an `Integer`.